# Вопрос насчет gspread python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Разрабатываю питон скрипт, который должен брать данные из одной группы, а после заносить некоторые данные в гугл таблицы. Код для вк я уже написал. Единственное "но", у меня возникает проблема с модулем gspread. Я импортирую его, подключаюсь к сервисному аккаунту через json, открываю таблицу по ссылке, а после пытаюсь выбрать страницу для работы. Вот тут как раз и появляется проблема: почему-то страницу он выбирает ровно 45 секунд. Причем, так всегда. После этого скрипт работает как обычно. Как можно исправить, чтобы подключение не занимало столько много времени? P.S. использую python 3.8.5 и gspread 3.6.0. Код прикладываю ниже:

```
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='<путь к json файлу>')
sh = gc.open_by_key("<ссылка на таблицу>")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Отчётная деятельность за октябрь")
```

У меня все отлично авторизовывается, открывается, а выбор страницы 45 секунд. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: при использовании `by_key` указывается не ссылка, а идентификатор. попробуйте выбирать не по имени листа, а по номеру `wks = gc.open(gdocument).sheet1`

Comment: Как ни удивительно, но через пару дней эта проблема сама собой прошла. Интересная штука, это программирования :D